# Could I implement a kill switch in my solidity program?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

I was wondering if there was a way to put a killswitch into my solidity code?
I am using v0.4.21+commit.dfe3193c

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Define *killswitch*.

Comment: I agree that "a killswitch" is a bit vague as a requisite

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You create a bool.

```
address public isPaused;
```

You create a modifier

```
modifier onlyIfRunning {
  require(!isPaused);
  _;
}
```

You decide which functions should freeze in the paused state (not necessarily everything). You add the modifier.

```
function deposit() public payable onlyIfRunning ...
```

You create a function to set the flag:

```
function pauseContract() public onlyOwner {
  isPaused = true;
}
```

You can optionally create an unPause function that sets `isPaused` back to `false`. If the contract can't do that, then `isPaused` is, effectively, "killed".

Open Zeppelin has a well-crafted Pausable contract. I'll leave to you do dig through commits to find a version that is compatible with 0.4.21. It existed at one time. https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/lifecycle/Pausable.sol

Implementation was as simple as:

```
import "./Pausable.sol";

contract MyContract is Pausable { ...
```

Pausable would do:

```
contract Pausable is Ownable { ...
```

So, a side effect is MyContact is, by extension, Ownable. You need some form of access control to support the notion that only certain people should be authorized to kill the contract.

In my opinion, this is far preferable to `selfdestruct` in most cases. https://blog.b9lab.com/selfdestruct-is-a-bug-9c312d1bb2a5

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a function like this:

```
address payable public owner;

modifier onlyOwner {
   require(msg.sender == owner);
   _;
}

constructor() public {
   owner = msg.sender;
}

function kill() public onlyOwner {
   selfdestruct(owner);
}
```

The kill function uses the `selfdestruct` function to "destroy" the contract making it unusable and effectively killing it. All the ether stored in the contract will be sent to the owner of the contract in that case.